# Two words which are made by decreasing letters of the first word

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, letters

> I'm six letters word, I usually work on two or more things;i also am a verb
>
> Remove the first two letters from me, I become a suffix
>
> Remove the first three letters in the first word, I become another suffix.

What are each of these three words?

Answer (score 2):

The answer could be

> **ruling**, usually mean to rule over more than one person. It can be a verb as well as an adverb or noun. It is also 6 letters in length.

As for the suffixes

> **[-ling](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ling)** is a suffix after removing two letters and
>  **[-ing](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ing)** is another suffix after removing three letters (the riddle didn't mention three 'more' letters).

Answer (score 1):

You could be

> ORATION,

because

> ORATION is normally done to a crowd of 2 or more people, -ATION is a [suffix](https://www.yourdictionary.com/ation), and -ION is another [suffix](https://www.yourdictionary.com/ion).

Although I think this riddle might be a bit too broad ... there are many suffixes ...

Comment: -ION removes 4 letters.